# Javascript Expand and Collapse

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript drag and drop functionality to expand and collapse my contents.
The following is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);

       if(e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'block';
       else
          e.style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1');" ><div class="gap">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</div></a>

<div id="id1" style="display:none;">This is foo</div>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');" ><div class="gap">Click here to see wonder</div></a>
<a href="#"  onclick="toggle_visibility('id3');">Edit</a>
<div id="id2">This is foo</div>
<div id="id3">Edit</div>
```

The problem is,when I click the Edit section should display.Now both edit and foo is displaying...

Please let me know the correct code to do this one.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: here you are not hiding the remaining divs.Just you are checking the current div

Comment: You are handling only entered id (argument). You have to handle other divs too.